# generating link using Url.Action with jquery href attr

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to generate a link using following

```
$(this).parent().attr('href', '@Url.Action("Create", "Home"' + '?clientId=' + clientId + '&clientName=' + clientName);
```

somewhere I read that I need to isolate this Url.Action with controller and action into variable so I tried with this

```
var a = '@Url.Action("Create", "Home"';
$(this).parent().attr('href', a + '?clientId=' + clientId + '&clientName=' + clientName);
```

But this still doesn't work.
In browser I'm getting

> http://localhost:1328/Home/Index2/@Url.Action%28%22Create%22,%20%22Home%22?clientId=181&clientName=undefined

Comment: That would mean that you script is in an external file - Razor code is not parsed n external files. You would need to create the base url in the main view (either a global variable or pass its value to your function)

Comment: can you please provide with example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to store the url with `data-*` attributes and access them. In the View you can add the below attribute:

```
data-url='@Url.Action("Create", "Home")'
```

Now you can access this in the script with:

```
var base = $(this).data('url');
$(this).parent().attr('href', base + '?clientId='+ clientId +'&clientName=' + clientName);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script should be on Razor page in order to make `@Url.Action` helper work.

When you place it there this should work:

```
//this line should generate /Home/Create string
var urlNoParam = '@Url.Action("Create", "Home")';
//and here you just add params as you want
$(this).parent().attr('href', urlNoParam  + '?clientId=' + clientId + '&clientName=' + clientName);
```